# How to copy a region of an image enclosed by cubic curves

Tags: image-processing, java-2d

I have a Java program that works very similar to the Bezier tool in Inkscape.  The purpose of my program is to allow the user to use the curves to draw a path around an object (like the head of a person) and then extract (copy) the pixels inside the enclosed curves.  In the attached picture, you can see that there are 3 blue curves that form an enclosed area.  I'd like to know how to copy the area enclosed by these 3 curves?  [image]

The code I use to draw the curves (I omit the red tangent lines and the red control points for simplicity):

```
        cubicCurve1 = new CubicCurve2D.Double(
            p1.x, p1.y, 
            p1Control1.x, p1Control1.y,
            p2Control1.x, p2Control1.y,
            p2.x, p2.y);

        cubicCurve2 = new CubicCurve2D.Double(
            p2.x, p2.y, 
            p2Control2.x, p2Control2.y,
            p3Control1.x, p3Control1.y,
            p3.x, p3.y);

        cubicCurve3 = new CubicCurve2D.Double(
                p3.x, p3.y, 
                p3Control2.x, p3Control2.y,
                p1Control1.x, p1Control1.y,
                p1.x, p1.y);

        g2D.setPaint(Color.BLUE);
    g2D.draw(cubicCurve1);    
    g2D.draw(cubicCurve2);
    g2D.draw(cubicCurve3);
```

Comment: If you do a polygon fill using your curve, the polygon will define the area you need to copy.

Comment: Sorry for this dummy question as I am new to Java: would you please show me your suggestion in code?  I looked but could not find any function of the class Polygon that would return me the area.

Comment: "If you do a polygon fill using your curve, the polygon will define the area you need to copy": alot of balooney

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I solved my problem:

```
        GeneralPath shape = new GeneralPath();
        shape.moveTo(cubicCurve1.x1, cubicCurve1.y1);
        shape.curveTo(cubicCurve1.ctrlx1, cubicCurve1.ctrly1, cubicCurve1.ctrlx2, cubicCurve1.ctrly2, cubicCurve1.x2, cubicCurve1.y2);
        shape.curveTo(cubicCurve2.ctrlx1, cubicCurve2.ctrly1, cubicCurve2.ctrlx2, cubicCurve2.ctrly2, cubicCurve2.x2, cubicCurve2.y2);
        shape.curveTo(cubicCurve3.ctrlx1, cubicCurve3.ctrly1, cubicCurve3.ctrlx2, cubicCurve3.ctrly2, cubicCurve1.x1, cubicCurve1.y1);
        g2D.draw(shape);
        g2D.setClip(shape);

        // Draw an image

        g2D.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);
```

Comment: I'm glad you were able to solve the problem on your own. I don't know enough Java to have been any help.

Comment: thank you Mark Ransom.  You suggestion did lead me to find my solution.  Thanks again